# Getting a string index based on a pixel offset

Tags: c#, graphics, textbox, drawing, measurement

I am custom drawing a text box and now I am implementing the part where the user can click on a line and have the cursor move to where he clicked.

I know how to get the row of text he clicked on because the character height is constant across all fonts, but not the column, because I'm not sure how to say "get me all the text that can be drawn before this amount of pixels," and because character width is not consistent unless you're using a fixed-width font, which is not a guarantee.

So I have the point from which I'm drawing the string (`0`) then I have the point that the user clicked. How do I get the string index of the character they clicked on?

**Extra info**: I am drawing the text by storing the lines in a List then iterating the list and using `Graphics.DrawString` on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple method to find the character at a pixel.

However you can find the pixels that a string will fill. Use the [Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges.aspx) method. You can perform a binary search on your string until you find the string where MeasureCharacterRanges returns your cursor position.

**Note:** You might see the *Graphics.MeasureString* method and be tempted to use that. DON'T! That method doesn't return accurate measurements. I can't remember why, but you will do your head in if you try!

Comment: Do all text editors have to do it this way? That is, does RichTextBox do it like this? Seems pretty hackish.

Comment: RichTextBox has a GetCharFromPosition method. This uses a native windows API message to get the character index.

Comment: Is there any way to use that? How does the underlying API message do it?

Comment: I'm afraid not unless you wish to use the windows Textbox control. The underlying API message is just voodoo as far as we are concerned.

Comment: If you are custom drawing your own text box you may want to look at the [SharpDevelop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpdevelop/) project. Their source is available and there is also an in depth book about how it was coded. In particular look at the ICSharpCode.TextEditor project.