# Best way to calculate the index of a character in a string given a pixel offset

Tags: c#, winforms, string, textbox, measure

Related question: [Getting a string index based on a pixel offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319954/getting-a-string-index-based-on-a-pixel-offset)

I know this is close to that question, but this isn't asking how to do it directly, it's asking how to fake it best.

---

I am implementing my own text box for Windows Forms (because RichTextBox sucks) and I am trying to find the best way to, given strings that have been drawn on the screen, calculate what character the mouse is over. The problem is that characters can be variable-width.

I have come up with two possibilities:

1. Do `Graphics.MeasureCharacterRange` **every time the mouse moves** in a binary search fashion on the line that the mouse is over (as suggested in the question linked at the top)
2. Keep a list of the offset of every character of every line.

(1) Will have bad performance, and

(2) will be memory-inefficient plus make typing a character become a O(n) operation (because you have to adjust the offset of every character after it) *plus* impossible to do precisely because `Graphics.MeasureCharacterRange` isn't precise (it returns one value for one character, another value for another character, and a totally different value [that does not equal the two previous values added together] for both of them together in one string. E.g. `W` will be 16 pixels wide and `f` will be 5 pixels wide, but `Wf` is 20 pixels wide. Those numbers are from an actual test.).

So I am looking for a better strategy to do this, preferably one that requires minimal space and O(1) computational complexity (though I will gladly trade off a little memory efficiency for speed efficiency).

Comment: do you have to keep the text in the text box or can you use alternative container, like div?

Comment: @Kris what's a div? I'm using winforms, not HTML. Forgive me if there's such a thing in winforms, I've never heard of it.

Comment: Doesn't even sound like an HTML question, is it a WinForms questions?

Comment: Evil premature optimization.  The mouse is moved by a human.

Comment: well, you edited the question to have the winform tag and the additional text "for Windows Forms (because RichTextBox sucks)", perhaps next time you will add that in initial question and please don't make it sound like I misread the question

Comment: @Kris yes I edited it to make it more clear. But I didn't know things such as `Graphics.MeasureCharacterRange` existed in HTML. Or that you could use C# in HTML. And misreading the question isn't a horrible thing, I do it all the time. Sorry. No need to downvote the question.

Comment: @Hans I don't want to decide this and build a bunch of stuff on top of it and later have to change it because it's slow and then have to change everything built on top of it too. That's the problem I have with the premature optimisation argument.

Comment: What is evil about it is undertaking the effort without *knowing if it is necessary*.  Measure.

Comment: @Hans I see what you mean, but _might be a massive waste of time_ for something that will probably be slow is enough for me to look for another way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to do O(1).   O(1) is assuming that every additional character has an affect on ALL previous characters, which it would not.  At best I would see an O(1) for each word which should be crazy fast.  It sounds like what you need is a way to store; 1 the location of each word, 2 each unique word, and 3 the width of each letter in the word.  This would significantly reduce the storage and increase look up speed.  Maybe something like:

```
IEnumerable<TextLocation> TextLocations = ...;

internal class TextLocation
{
    public RectF BoundingBox { get; set; }  //this is relative to the textbox
    public TextWord TextWord { get; set; }
}

internal class TextWord
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LetterInfo> Letters { get; set; }
}

internal class LetterInfo
{
    public char Letter { get; set; }
    public float left { get; set; }  //these would be relative to the bounding box
    public float right { get; set; } //not to the textbox
}
```

Then you might be able to do something like

```
var tl = TextLocations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BoundingBox.Left < Mouse.X 
                                           && x.BoundingBox.Right > Mouse.X
                                           && x.BoundingBox.Top < Mouse.Y
                                           && x.BoundingBox.Bottom > Mouse.Y)

if (tl != null)
{
    //tl.TextWord.Text is the Word ("The", "Lazy", "Dog"...)

    var letter = tl.TextWord.Letters
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => Mouse.x - tl.BoundingBox.left > x.left
                                        Mouse.x - tl.BoundingBox.left < x.right);

    if (letter != null)
    {
        // you get the idea
    }                              
}
```

Comment: This would be O(n) anyway because you have to recalculate the position of every word after the character you type on that line. And I can't store words as seperated by spaces because of syntax highlighting. Thanks though.

Comment: I did write a print algorithm to determine pages before print using the `Graphics.MeasureString`, and I believe the issue was making sure the Graphics used had a DPI equal to or greater than the actual comparable.  When using a monitor I used 300 DPI and when priting I used 1800 DPI, but only of MeasureString, not for actual printing.

Comment: So what you are saying is that every character type in a textbox affect the width of EVERY single character before that?  I know it doesn't work that way, not for any font.  The only exception would be if you were using a weird alignment(center) or full justification (which isn't supported automatically).

Comment: Not before, but after, and on the same line. And not the width, but offset. This is taking for granted that my textbox doesn't do line wrapping, in which case it would affect every character after the one typed, not only on the same line, but on all lines after the one that got the new character.

Comment: But by recalculating the word that was edited, you know the offset to apply to all words on that line.  Nothing needs to be recalculated, only the `TextLocation.BoundingBox.Left` and `TextLocation.BoundingBox.Right' need be updated with the new offset.

Comment: what I mean is you have to go through every word after the one you typed and add that offset to them. That means it's O(n). Besides, like I said, I can't break the text up into words.